# How can I extend the CMS Page When using Magento Enterprise

Tags: cms, magento-enterprise

I am using Magento enterprise and want to add an additional field to the CMS page form in the backend.

Is there anything special to take care of, to not break the CMS versioning feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Add your custom field to the tables `cms/page` as well as `enterprise_cms/page_revision`
- Create the form field in an observer for the event `adminhtml_cms_page_edit_tab_content_prepare_form`
- Rewrite `Enterprise_Cms_Model_Config` to add your field to the property `_revisionControlledAttributes`. If this is not done, the `Enterprise_Cms` would not automatically create a new revision, if only the new custom field was changed